# C : when asking for 2 inputs from a user the 2nd question will not prompt an input to be stored in a variable

Tags: c, scanf, fgets

If I try grade or fullname one at a time I will get the expected result

```
"Enter your Grade: "
"Your grade is x"

"Enter your full name:"
"Your full name is xxxx  xxxx"
```

If I run below the print out is

```
Enter your Grade:2
Your grade is 2
Enter your full name:  Your full name is
```

I can't figure out why I am not been prompted for a second input especially as I know it works when tried on its own */

```
int main()
{

    char grade;
    printf("Enter your Grade: ");
    scanf("%c", &grade);
    printf("Your grade is %c \n", grade);



    char fullName[20];
    printf("Enter your full name:  ");
    fgets(fullName, 20, stdin); /*2nd argument specify limits of inputs*, 3rd means standard input ie command console */
    printf("Your full name is %s \n", fullName);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remember that the `Enter` key will add a newline in the input buffer. And that this newline will not be read by `scanf("%c", &grade);`. Which means that the first character read by `fgets` will be this newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%c");` buffer problem, `%c` will only eat one character, so   or `\n` will stay in the buffer for the next one to read.

Try this

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char grade;
    printf("Enter your Grade: ");
    scanf("%c", &grade);
    getchar(); // here
    printf("Your grade is %c \n", grade);

    char fullName[20];
    printf("Enter your full name:  ");
    fgets(fullName, 20, stdin); /*2nd argument specify limits of inputs*, 3rd means standard input ie command console */
    printf("Your full name is %s \n", fullName);

    return 0;
}
```

use `getchar();` to eat the extra character in the buffer.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I got it to work, could I also ask, I also tried removing `\n` from my code so there would not be anything in the buffer and didn't use `getchar()` but got the same issue, I'm not sure I understand why, if `%c` takes once character and there is no ` ` or `\n` should it not run the same as using `getchar()`?

Comment: my thoughts are removing any ` ` or `\n` would resolve the buffer issue

Comment: @Spooky what do you mean by removing `\n` from your code ?

Comment: @PhilippeB.`char grade;
    printf("Enter your Grade: ");
    scanf("%c", &grade);
    printf("Your grade is %c \n", grade);` // taking out the \n here i though would resolve the buffer problem

Comment: @Spooky no you missunderstood. The `\n` is coming from your input. When you hit `enter` to register your first input, `scanf("%c", &grade);` reads your character and the `enter` key you pressed (`\n`) is sent into the buffer. Which means when you use `fgets` it will read from the buffer and see `\n` which is your `enter` key pressed from the first input.

Comment: @PhilippeB.ahh ok, I get it now, thank you for the clarification, appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix `scanf()` with `fgets()` - in this case, the newline present in the buffer, left untouched by `scanf()` will be fed to `fget()` and it won't "ask" for any new input.

Better to use `fgets()` in all the user-inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this line `scanf("%c", &grade);` Whenever you use `scanf()` always keep in mind that the `enter` key will be stored in your buffer. Since `enter` key was in your buffer, it went right into `fullName` when `fgets(fullName, 20, stdin);` is executed. That's way you got your output:

```
Enter your Grade:2    
Your grade is 2
Enter your full name:  Your full name is
```

You can solve the problem by using `getchar();` or `getch();` right after `scanf();` to capture the `Enter` key and ensures that `fullName` get the correct input. Another way to solve it is to use `fflush(stdin);`. They basically do the same thing, but `fflush(stdin);` clear `Enter` key from the buffer. Therefore, `fflush(stdin);` should be used after `scanf();` to clear the unwanted `Enter` key left by `scanf();`

This is a long one and have a lot to take in, but I hope this information helps :)))

Comment: thank you for the explanation and break down its very helpful